# What is unique in MYSQL? Can I put unique to prevent repeated entries?

Tags: mysql

I am new to programming.

May I know what is unique in MYSQL?

I have 2 more question which not to sure, I have stated below

1 )I am generating serial number which cannot be repeated can I mark it as unique?

2) For registration- email input by user cannot repeated, can i mark it as unique too?

Answer (score 0):

An auto-generated number should probably be the primary key of a table.  A primary key is unique and not null.

If email can only appear once in a table, then you can/should declare it unique.  Note that this is not a suggestion.  The database will reject any `insert` or `update` statement that attempts to insert a duplicate value.

Answer (score 0):

A unique constraint is a single field or combination of fields that uniquely defines a record. Some of the fields can contain null values as long as the combination of values is unique.

For both your questions --- Yes you can create unique fields

refer this link for more [info](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/unique.php)